# How can I make a table that only shows items from the person that logged in?

Tags: php, database, session, mysqli

I've just started programming and I can't seem to figure this out. I want to only show the dvds from the person that logged in.

I have 3 tables:

users:

```
    user_id | username | password
    1         user1      pass1
    2         user2      pass2
    3         user3      pass3
```

dvds:

```
    dvd_id | title       | year | rating
    1        Ex Machina    2015   7.7
    2        Cloud Atlas   2012   7.5
    3        The Matrix    1999   8.7
```

And the bridge table, dvd_users: (it should be possible to have multiple dvd's as user and a dvd should be able to be used again)

```
    user_id | dvd_id
    1         1
    1         3
    2         2
```

I've made a login form which works, but I'm unable to show a table with de user that just logged in and al the dvds that belong to him. This is my code to do so:

```
$_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['pword'] = $_POST['password'];    

$sql = "SELECT dvds.dvd_id, dvds.title, dvds.year, dvds.rating, users.user_id, users.username 
        FROM dvds 
        WHERE username = '$_POST[username]';
        INNER JOIN dvd_users 
        ON dvds.dvd_id=dvd_users.dvd_id 
        INNER JOIN users 
        ON dvd_users.user_id=users.user_id";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                echo "<table>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){                                  
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['rating'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";       
                    }
                echo "</table>";
            }
            else{
                echo "No results found.";
            }
```

How can I solve this problem? I want to show a table with dvds that only belong to the user that has just logged in, so for example, when user1 has logged in:

```
    title       | year | rating
    Ex Machina    2015   7.7
    The Matrix    1999   8.7
```

Comment: store `user_id` into session as well an put it after login in the `WHERE` clause of your query in order to fetch only user related db records. your current sql query is wrong.

Comment: for starters remove the quotes around the variable in your query

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added it and changed some other things, and it works now!